# PN532 can't read NFC card type B

Tags: raspberry-pi, nfc, credit-card, contactless-smartcard

I'm trying to use the PN532 by Elechouse V3 connected through i2c to the raspberry-pi to read debit and credit card and I manage to read the type-A card successfully.
I can't read the type-b cards though.

These are the step I'm following according to the manual 
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/141520.pdf:

- Setting SAM configuration to normal mode sending bytes [0xD4, 0x14, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00] (not sure this is required though)
- Sending InListPassiveTarget with bytes [0xD4, 0x4A, 0x01, 0x03, 0x01]

I was expecting to be able to read the type-B cards at this point but nothing happens when I try to put a card close to the reader.

I've also tried changing the RF configuration settings sending the bytes
[0xD4, 0x32, 0x0C, 0xFF, 0x17, 0x85] before the InListPassiveTarget and also tried using the InAutoPoll method with all the possible values but still no luck.

Any idea or suggestion would be really appreciated

Comment: Have you tried setting the last byte (AFI) of InListPassiveTarget to zero (`D4 4A 01 03 00`)?

Comment: @MichaelRoland I tried that already and it doesn't work. Thanks for the comment though

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this, i.e. RF parameters that work? I am stuck with the same problem